# Issue loading properties file in spring

Tags: java, spring

spring app context file and application.properties files are located under:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring
```

When I try to load properties file:

```
<context:property-placeholder local-override="true" location="classpath:/META_INF/spring/application.properties"/>
```

Getting error:

```
class path resource [META_INF/spring/application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I also tried:

```
<context:property-placeholder local-override="true" location="classpath:application.properties"/>

<context:property-placeholder local-override="true" location="application.properties"/>
```

Comment: `META-INF != META_INF`.

Comment: You seems to have a typo.. you should use META-INF instead of META_INF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<context:property-placeholder local-override="true" location="classpath:/META-INF/spring/application.properties"/>
```

instead of:

```
<context:property-placeholder local-override="true" location="classpath:/META_INF/spring/application.properties"/>
```